# How do I configure my server to start with an Angular project?

Tags: angular

I am on Windows, and I compile my Angular project using Putty.
So I don't use Git, and I don't test my app locally.

Instead, I work directly on my server.

I try to follow this Hero tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0

I have compiled my project on my server like this:

```
cd freelancer
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

It compiles successfully.

It is the only project on my server.

Now when I go to my website http://217.160.44.200/ it shows me the Plesk Start Page instead of my project:

[image]

I expected that going to the start page of my server would show me the app right away. However, it shows that Plesk start page.

Now when I go to http://217.160.44.200/freelancer or http://217.160.44.200/freelancer/index.html instead, it says "404 The requested URL was not found on this server."

This is what it looks like when viewed in an ftp program:

[image]

How could I actually view my project now?

Answer (score 0):

Using ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 will allow you to connect to the ng serve using your IP instead of localhost. If you want to see in your local machine I would remove the --host 0.0.0.0 and just pass ng serve within the freelancer directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "with the freelancer directory"? like this "ng serve freelancer"?

Comment: I have run this command,  but when I visit my server (or myserver/freelancer), it's not found.

Comment: I mean to say change the directory to freelancer which is the root folder of your application  and try ng serve

Comment: IF you look at the image it could make sense

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Just run ng build —prod and ftp the contents of the dist folder to your server..

Comment: @MikeOne When I run "ng build —prod", it says "An unhandled exception occured: Project '-prod' does not exist."

Comment: @MikeOne Where is the "dist" folder?

Comment: Those are two dashes you need. Maybe just do some tutorials first on angular.io ..?

Comment: Point is, you need to build your app before you can put it on a remote server.

Comment: I am trying to follow along this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0 However, I don't want to work on my machine. I work remotely on my server.

Comment: I have connected to my remote machine / the server using Putty. So I have already built and deployed my app, and there is no need to put it on the server. Because it already IS on my server. I don't use GIT. I work directly on my server.

Comment: @MikeOne You mistyped... it should actually be "ng build --prod".

Comment: @MikeOne After "ng build --prod", I have the dist folder now. Thank you. In that folder, I have "index.html". However, when I go to my page, it says 404 Not found. The URL is https://217.160.44.200/freelancer/dist/freelancer/index.html

Comment: @MIkeOne I think your "ng build --prod" + dist folder solution is the answer. If you like you can post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MikeOne answered the question in the comment section, I would be glad if he posted the answer. Just in case he doesn't do it, I will write down his solution:

```
 ng build --prod
```

This creates a folder named "dist".
It contains all the necessary, compiled files including an index.html file.

The contents of this "dist" folder should be put into the /var/www/html folder.